# What's the meaning of うろんな貝 in this sentence?

Tags: sentence

> なんだかこの会話自体がズレているようで居心地が悪いし、情報が少なすぎるし、そもそも、断るつもりなら今頃ベッドの上で**うろんな貝**の気分になっている。

I went to search the meaning and I find that うろん = 胡乱. With a literal translation it is "A suspicious-looking shell", but this is in the end a literal translation and I like to know if this is a idiomatic expression or anything like that.

The context:

> 「先生。これが笑い話なら、そろそろ帰っていいでしょうか？」
> 「いや、ごめんごめん、謝るよ。冗談じゃなくて真面目な話なんだ。ちょっと、君の手を借りたくてね」
> 「本当に、転入生の問題で？」
> 「うん、訳ありというか、難しいというか。彼……草十郎くんというんだけど、ちょっと、色々とズレていてね。僕らが案内してあげるより、同世代の君の方が適任だと思ったんだ」
> 「…………」
> 　彼女は不審げに表情を曇らせた。
> 　教師の業務を生徒に押しつけるのも怠慢だが、それ以上にその転入生が『ズレている』とはどういう事だろう？
> 　素行に問題がある、扱いが難しい、というのなら想像しやすい。しかし、ズレている、というのは何なのか。
> 『ズレてるなんて、そう使わない表現だけど……』
> 　彼女は不審げに思案するも、すぐに頭を切りかえた。
> 　あれこれ悩んでも仕方がない。
> 　なんだかこの会話自体がズレているようで居心地が悪いし、情報が少なすぎるし、そもそも、断るつもりなら今頃ベッドの上でうろんな貝の気分になっている。

Comment: What is 断る referring to?

Comment: In this context, "To refuse the request".

Comment: Sure, but what request? I can’t seem to find it in the passage you provided. Who is requesting what from whom?

Comment: Sorry, it seems that the context is insufficient, I'll edit. But the context is basically a professor calling a student for a request. The request is that the student helps in introducing the school for a transfer student.

Comment: I can't recall any common idiom related to うろんな貝. To add to it, the passage 断るつもりなら〜なっている is still hard to interpret (even literally) with this much of context. I speculate that it might need some knowledge of the plot to understand the phrase correctly.

Comment: 同じく全然分かりません…キャラ名から調べた限り出典は「魔法使いの夜」だと思いますが、貝とは一切関係なさそうです

Comment: うろこな貝 would mean "scaly shell" wouldn't it? Could it be a typo?

Answer (score 1):

> ベッドの上でうろんな貝の気分になっている。

This passage brings to me an image of someone curled up on the bed, like a huge mollusk retreating into its shell. With this little context I can't figure who exactly is this about and why would they feel like that.